# JDE XE to 9.2 Upgrade

Tags: jdedwards

I am trying to upgrade Archived Data in JDE XE to JDE 9.2

I have my archived Data in a Seperate Library and I want to use that as the Source for Loading the Data into the Target Library

Can you please let me know where I can provide the Source and Target in the Upgrade Plan

Thanks
Ajith